# Additional flag weight for double flagging a question?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-weight

Do you get additional flag weight for marking a question as `spam` or `offensive` along with `low quality` as well? Why is this type of double-flagging allowed?

Answer (score 3):

Double flagging is allowed because moderators review every flag.  If we notice you abusing the flagging mechanism we can always start declining your flags.  It has happened, but it's very rare.